# How to have separate arguments/variables in read

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, variable, user-interface

I want to make a CLI using bash for fun. I want to have a read prompt like

```
CLI/[path]/:>
```

easy

```
read -p "CLI$PWD/:>"
```

but if I want to do a command like `cd` then I will have to make a whole interface to change the directory. I know how to do all of the other basic commands, but my main goal is to be able to switch my directory in one command.

EG:

```
CLI/[path]/:>cd [another path]
CLI/[another path]/:>
```

My script so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Welcome to Easy Command-Line Interface! Type 'help' for help and 
commands."

while true; do

    read -p "ECLI$PWD/:>"
    if [ $REPLY = "help" ]; then
        echo "ECLI HELP:"
        echo "help: Help Menu"
        echo "cd: <dir> : Changes Directory"
        echo "say: <text> : Prints <text>"
        echo "exit: Exits ECLI"
        echo "clear: Clears screen"
        echo "
        "
    fi

    if [ $REPLY = "exit" ]; then
        echo "Exiting ECLI.."
        sleep 1.5
        clear
        break
    fi

    if [ $REPLY = "clear" ]; then
        clear
    fi


done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you’ve got to start using quotes. 
Surely you’ve noticed that

```
if [ $REPLY = "command" ]
```

fails
(and gives a `[: too many arguments` error message)
if you type a command line with more than one word. 
You need to change that to

```
if [ "$REPLY" = "command" ]
```

#### Approach 1: Read the line and extract the first word

I presume you understand that your current script
gets an entire input line into `$REPLY`. 
But, if the user types `cd /usr/local`,
it does you no good to compare `cd /usr/local` to `cd`;
you need to extract the first word of the input line. 
You can do this with `word1="${REPLY%% *}"`. 
This is an instance of parameter expansion,
which you can read about in [bash(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#EXPANSION) or [the POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02). 
So you could modify your script as follows:

```
     ︙
    if [ "$REPLY" = "clear" ]; then
        clear
    fi
 
    word1="${REPLY%% *}"
    if [ "$word1" = cd ]
    then
        $REPLY
    fi
     ︙
```

#### Approach 2: Read the first word separately

It’s rare that you want to read an entire line;
more often (as in this example) you want the shell
to break the line apart into words. 
You do this by giving the `read` command a list of variables to read into:

```
     ︙
    read -p "ECLI$PWD/:>" cmd args
     ︙

    if [ "$cmd" = "clear" ]; then
        clear
    fi

    if [ "$cmd" = cd ]
    then
        cd "$args"
    fi
     ︙
```

#### Approach 3: Read each word separately

The above approaches are fine for proof-of-concept toys. 
In a real application, you would want the shell to break the input line
into however many words there are. 
You do that by reading into an array, using the `-a` option:

```
     ︙
    read -p "ECLI$PWD/:>" -a arr
     ︙
 
    if [ "${arr[0]}" = "clear" ]; then
        clear
    fi
 
    if [ "${arr[0]}" = cd ]
    then
        cd "${arr[1]}"
    fi
     ︙
```

Comment: thank you! this is exactly what I needed! Approach 1 worked for me, I edited the code a bit so it couldn't go outside my projects main folder! I have asked this question many times, and it was misunderstood, now I finally have what I need!